# Mapping of http returned observable result in null object

Tags: typescript, angular, observable

I am doing a http request to my backend getTest method. Thata the data returned from the server tested with fiddler:

```
{
  "number": "1a",
  "testId": 1,
  "testNumber": 5,
  "testDate": "2016-05-20T00:00:00",
  "assignedPupils": [],
  "unAssignedPupils": []
}
```

Something is wrong with the subscribe or rather - so I assume - with the .map function but I am not sure. When I try to debug the mapping I never get into the EditTest class :/ and the error message shows the error in the bound html which is way too late. I need to know WHY 'test' object is undefined!

Anyone sees the problem?

```
export class EditTestComponent implements OnInit {
    test: EditTest;

    constructor(
        private _testsService: TestsService,
        private _routeParams: RouteParams)
    { }

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
        this._testsService.getTest(id).subscribe(test => this.test = test.map(t => new EditTest(t))); 
    }

}


TestService.ts:

 getTest(id) {
        return this.http.get('api/tests/edit/' + id).map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Html:

```
<div>
    <label>id: </label>{{test.id}}
    <label>number: </label>{{test.number}}
    <label>date: </label>{{test.date}}
</div>
```

I get this exception:

```
XCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in [{{test.id}}
         in EditTestComponent@3:27]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing `{{test.id}}` before `test` gets the assigned value from the backend. The error will actually stop the script from execution and will never even get to the `map`. To overcome this problem, use the Elvis Operator `?`

From [Angular.io cheat sheet](https://angular.io/cheatsheet):

> `<p>Employer: {{employer?.companyName}}</p>`
>   The safe navigation operator (?) means that the employer field is optional and if undefined, the rest of the expression should be ignored.

Use it like this:

```
<div>
    <label>id: </label>{{test?.id}}
    <label>number: </label>{{test?.number}}
    <label>date: </label>{{test?.date}}
</div>
```

Also, you didn't show the constructor of `EditTest`, so I assume it takes the properties and assign them.

Comment: Yes! that really helped , thx ;-) Just asked myself why that same error never occured with angular 1.x using NOT reactive extensions like .subscribe(). Is there not a general configuration setting to do a null check before a property is access?

Comment: Better working is this:   <div *ngIf="test">
        <b>id: </b>{{test.id}}
  
    </div> then I have not to do the ?-operator on every property :)